# Rust is the automatic dereference of Box types prohibative?

Tags: rust, type-theory, language-theory

Method calls on `Box` objects in Rust automatically dereference the object contained in the `Box` wrapper.

For example

```
let my_variable: std::boxed::Box<i32> = std::boxed::Box::new(42);

let my_new_variable = my_variable.ilog2();
```

This example is contrived. The important concept here is that a function (in this case `ilog2`) can be called on some type (in this case `i32`) which is wrapped in a box.

In C++, the dereference and function call operator would be required:

```
// C++ would require this
my_new_variable = my_variable->ilog2();
```

My question is the following:

- Does the automatic dereferencing of "boxed" objects prevent functions being called on the `Box` type itself? Are such function calls implicitly *prohibited*?

To further elaborate:

The type `Box` contains a function called `leak`.

- How would one call the function `leak()` on a Box object if method calls implicitly dereference the contents of the box?
- If calling a function which is associated with a Box object, on a Box object, "just works", then how would one disambiguate between two function calls which have the same name?(One associated with the `Box` and one associated with the type contained in the `Box`)

Syntactically:

If `Box` wraps type `T` such that we have `Box<T>`, and `Box` has a function `Box::leak()` and `T` has a function `T::leak()`, how do we disambiguate between the two function calls?

Comment: "how do we disambiguate between the two function calls" - there is no ambiguity. Even if by "If Box wraps type T" you mean `let b = Box::new(T)`. Dereferencing only works on methods, not on associated functions.

Comment: In the case of `Box` there are no methods that could conflict. In particular, `leak` isn't a method but an associated function and so is called with `Box::leak (b)` and not `b.leak()`.

Comment: From the documentation, how do I tell the difference between associated functions and methods? The difference between traits and these things is obvious.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: methods are those that accept `self` in some form.

Comment: Ah yes, that would make sense. So does this mean it is impossible for the Rust language to add a new method to the Box object? Is that actually prohibited by the language itself, or is it a standards committee thing where the people who define what `Box` is just agree not to add any methods to it?

Answer (score 3):

The details of this can be found in the reference on [Method call expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html). The gist of it is the following

> For instance, if the receiver has type Box<[i32;2]>, then the
> candidate types will be Box<[i32;2]>, &Box<[i32;2]>, &mut
> Box<[i32;2]>, [i32; 2] (by dereferencing), &[i32; 2], &mut [i32; 2],
> [i32] (by unsized coercion), &[i32], and finally &mut [i32].

That is, if `Box<T>` had a method `.quack()`, and `T` had a method of the same name, a method call like `foo.quack()` where `foo` is of type `Box<T>` would refer to the implementation `Box::quack()`; the `T::quack()` is effectively shadowed. As to your question, this does *not* prevent the `Box`-type (or any other `Deref`-type) from implementing methods that their inner type also implements, or vice versa.

For example:

```rust
struct Foo<T>(T);

impl<T> std::ops::Deref for Foo<T> {
    type Target = T;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn quack(&self) {
        println!("foo!");
    }
}

struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn quack(&self) {
        println!("bar!")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foobar = Foo(Bar);
    // This will print "foo!".
    // Removing/renaming `Foo:quack` prints "bar!" without any change here
    foobar.quack();
}
```

In almost all cases, this behavior brings convenience to calling methods on any `T` that is wrapped in a smart-pointer. In order to *visually/mentally* disambiguate calls to methods on `T` vs. methods on the smart-pointer itself, smart-pointers usually don't have methods by themselves but only associated functions. `Box::leak()` is one example, and there are [many others](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap), which enforce a syntax like `Box::leak(foo);` instead of `foo.leak();` for *visual* disambiguity.

One example where there is visual/mental ambiguity is the `Clone` implementation on `Rc`/`Arc`, where calling `foo.clone()` *looks like* cloning the inner `T`, while in fact, one is only cloning (increasing the reference count) of the outer `Rc`/`Arc`.

Comment: My question perhaps wasn't quite clear - by "prevent" I effectively meant what you refer to here as "shadowing". This seems to be quite a serious flaw in the Rust language. I have no idea why this decision was made. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You are welcome to have an opinion on the wisdom of Rust's design, albeit any such opinions are not the topic of this platform. Regarding the last comment on the original question: Yes, because adding `Box<T>::quack()` to `Box<T>` would mean that existing `T::quack()` would get overruled during method-lookup, breaking existing code. This has not come up as a serious problem. Since the interaction of MRO and Deref only applies to smart-pointers, the DWIM-gains are considered a net positive. You can read more about this [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)

Comment: It's not really my opinion - if the case ever occurs where someone wishes to implement two functions with the same name, one of which resides on a Box type, then the language is fundamentally broken, because there is no way to access that method on the Box, and it can only be called on the type contained within the Box. That's not a matter of opinion, it is literally broken by design. Whether this comes up frequently in practice is of course debatable. I don't doubt this situation doesn't occur because of the contract to never implement a "self" method on a Box type... (1/2)

Comment: However, someone may implement their own container with dereference symantics. If they do so, and don't honor the contract to not implement "self-methods" (in C++ we call them member functions) then Rust by design, is broken. It cannot produce the correct and intended compiled output under some circumstances. (2/2)

Comment: You can always call `Bar::quack(&foobar)` if you want `Bar`'s `quack()`

Comment: Or `(*foobar).quack()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using method syntax you can always fall back to the fully qualified names so even if `Foo::quack` is shadowing `Bar::quack` you can still use it, with the  defnitions of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76073584/442760):

```rust
fn main() {
    let foobar = Foo(Bar);
    // This will print "foo!".
    // Removing/renaming `Foo:quack` prints "bar!" without any change here
    foobar.quack();
    Foo::quack(&foobar); // will print "foo!" no matter what
    Bar::quack(&foobar); // will print "bar!" no matter what

}
```